# division of two PDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to solve the following question. I have come up a solution to this but need to know that is my approach correct in solving the question. The question is as follows

A Test is 1 hour long, and has two questions. The time you give to Q1 is represented by the random variable , which has the following PDF:

$f_Z(z)= 
\begin{cases}
    12z(1-z)^2,& \text{if } 0 \leq z\leq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

The rest of the time is given to Q2. The value of Z is chosen based on the relative lengths of the questions.
Let  be the ratio between the time you give to the longer question and the time you give the shorter question:

= longer question / shorter question.

Note that  ≥ 1.

a) Find ( ≤ 2)

b) Find the probability distribution of  i.e. ( ≤ )

$\\$

Well i am doing it in the following way

First of all changing hour unit to minutes the PDF of z will now become

$f_Z(z)= 
\begin{cases}
    720z(1-60z)^2,& \text{if } 0 \leq z\leq 60\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

and the PDF of Q2 $= 1 - f_Z(z)$

so the of $X$ will become

$f_X(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{720z(1-60z)^2}{1 - 720z(1-60z)^2},& \text{if } 30 \leq z\leq 60\\
    \frac{1 - 720z(1-60z)^2}{720z(1-60z)^2},& \text{if } 0 \leq z\leq 30\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that PDF of $1-Z$ is not $1-f_Z(z)$ and also PDF of $U/V$ is not the ratio of PDF's of $U$ and $V$. Note also that your PDF of $Z$ in minutes is not PDF: it integrates not to 1 but to 8391860496000.

If I understand the question correctly, $X=\frac{\max(Z,1-Z)}{\min(Z,1-Z)}$.

First of all, you can solve inequality $X\leq 2$ with respect to $Z$:
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\frac{\max(Z,1-Z)}{\min(Z,1-Z)} \leq 2.
$$
Consider separately the cases $Z\leq \frac12$ and $Z>\frac12$.

In the first case $\max(Z, 1-Z)=1-Z$, $\min(Z,1-Z)=Z$ and the equality (\ref{1}) leads to $1-Z\leq 2Z$ or $\frac13\leq Z\leq \frac12$.

Solve the equality for the second case the same way and get $\frac12 < Z\leq \frac23$.

Then find probability in (a) as
$$
\mathbb P(X\leq 2)= \mathbb P\left(\frac{\max(Z,1-Z)}{\min(Z,1-Z)} \leq 2\right) = \mathbb P\left(\frac13\leq Z \leq \frac23\right) = \int\limits_{1/3}^{2/3} f_Z(z)\,dz.$$

In (b) replace $2$ by $x$ and repeat.